# General construction of ramified covering of projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety, $D$ be an effective divisor, suppose there exists an invertible sheaf $L$ such that $L^n=\mathcal{O}(D)$, then we could obtain a cyclic cover $p:\tilde{X}\to X$ by taking n-th root out of $D$. If we denote $G$ be the deck transformation group of this covering, then $G=\mathbb{Z}_n$. I know the paper of [Pardini](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1991.417.191/html) who generalized the construction to ramified covering with $G$ an abelian group.

My question is:

> Is there any algebraic construction of a ramified covering along an effective divisor $D$ with $G=S_n$, where $S_n$ is the symmetric group for n elements?

From topological point of view, the covering with $G=S_n$ will be equivalent of existence a representation $\rho:\pi_1(X\setminus D)\to S_n$ and the kernel of this map gives a n-fold covering. However, is there a building data for such kind of $\rho$ to exists?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  What kind of answer are you looking for?  Do you want a description as a "flat multisection" in a rank $n$ vector bundle with an algebraically integrable connection?  Do you want a description in terms of local monodromies around intersecting branches of the branch divisor that are not "too" commutative?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at

H. Tsuchihashi: [Galois coverings of projective varieties for dihedral and symmetric groups](https://doi.org/10.2206/kyushujm.57.411), *Kyushu J. Math.* **57**, No. 2, 411-427 (2003). [ZBL1072.14018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1072.14018).